# requirejs: is there a way to set several places for search for 1 resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I need to implement something very common to the view resolve algorithm in .net MVC but with requirejs - if the resource is not present in the folder search for it in the shared folder.

Do you know if that is possible with requirejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certianly, you will have to include pathconfig fallbacks, taken directly from requirejs manual.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks

```
requirejs.config({
//To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
enforceDefine: true,
paths: {
    jquery: [
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
        //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
        'lib/jquery'
    ]
}
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```